# Does the Innovator medal scale with level?

Tags: ingress

When the medal *Innovator* was awarded, you got the color based on your current level at that moment. Now that the event related to this is over, does the medal scale when you level up? I.e. will my silver *Innovator* medal become gold when I reach level eleven in, say, a week from now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately that medal was time limited with the related event dates. The level of the Innovator badge you've got at that time will never change. (Btw I'm the living proof of it; with the release of the new Spec Ops, Trekker, and Engineer badges I've just become level 11 and my Innovator level didn't change.)

Comment: FWIW, I got gold Innovator---it didn't upgrade when I hit L13 or L14.